# remove duplicate values in a text file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, linux-terminal, textwrangler

I have a tab delimnated text file showing a comparison. 
like this:

```
    A   B   C   D 
A   1   2   3   4
B   2   1   4   3
C   3   4   1   2
D   4   3   2   1
```

But I need to work with the data later in another program which need the table to be like this:

> A
>   B 2
>   C 3 4
>   D 4 3 2

Does anyone know how I could do that with excel, terminal or textwrangler?
the data set is really huge and I could not do it manually.

Comment: I don't understand how it is determining what is a duplicate. Would you please clarify?

Comment: You haven't specified any parameters for how duplicates are determined.

Answer (score 1):

Get the table into Excel. Let the data table start with the blank cell above the A value in cell A1. See the screenshot of the input sheet

Try this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub convert()


Dim wssrc As Worksheet
Dim wstarget As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lrow As Long

Set wssrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

wssrc.Activate
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print lrow

For i = 1 To lrow
    wssrc.Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, i)).Copy wstarget.Range("A" & i)
Next i

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of the input sheet:

[image]

This is a screenshot of the output sheet.

[image]